# How to .htaccess redirect this URL with a query string?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

While using a WordPress maintenance plugin, I ended up with this query string URL that I now need to redirect to root when the site goes live.

```
http://mydomain.com/maintenance/?req=http%3A%2F%mydomain.com%2F
```

What will redirect that URL to simply `http://mydomain.com`?

I've tried both of these:

```
Redirect 301 "http://mydomain.com/maintenance/?req=http://mydomain.com/" http://mydomain.com

Redirect 301 "http://mydomain.com/maintenance/?req=http%3A%2F%mydomain.com%2f" http://mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put these lines in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} req=http%3A%2F%2F(.+)%2F [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} req=http://([^&]+)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^maintenance/?$ http://%1? [L,R,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, works great! How would I do a redirect from the original string to a page like mydomain.com/update/ (that shows a link to mydomain.com) so I can advise users to update bookmarks after they click and go to mydomain.com?

Comment: You mean redirecting URI `/maintenance/?req=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2F` to `http://mydomain.com/update` ? That can be simple done by having last line of above rule like `RewriteRule ^maintenance/?$ http://%1/update/? [L,R,NC,NE]`

Answer (score 0):

[`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) does only work with the URL path. You need to use [*the real* mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to look at the query:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =req=http://example.com/
RewriteRule ^maintenance/$ /? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, but couldn't get this to work; it was in the correct place, after RewriteEngine on and before the WP rewrite block.